# why this code works fine in c++ if i use cin but it fails when i use scanf in c?

Tags: c

I wrote below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char o,r;
    int x,y;
    do {
        printf("Enter operator: '+' or '-' or '*' or '/'\n");
        scanf("%c",&o);
        printf("Enter first number: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        printf("Enter second number: ");
        scanf("%d",&y);
        switch(o) {
            case '+':
                printf("Sum: %d",x+y);
                break; 
            case '-':
                printf("Subtract: %d",x-y);
                break;
            case '*':
                printf("Multiply: %d",x*y);
                break;
            case '/':
                printf("Division: %d",x/y);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong operator entered.");
        }
        printf("\nEnter y or Y to continue: ");
        scanf("%c",&r); // r is not getting value?. why?
    } while((r=='y')||(r=='Y'));
}
```

r is not getting value thus it is not doing what it supposed to do.

```
printf("\nEnter y or Y to continue: ");
scanf("%c",&r);
```

What seems to be the problem? Am I missing something?

Why does this code work fine in c++ if I use `cin,` but it fails when I use `scanf` in c?

Comment: For me (gcc 4.8.2) this code "fails"  both in `C` and `C++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char o,r;
    int x,y;
    do{
        printf("Enter operator: '+' or '-' or '*' or '/'\n");
        scanf(" %c",&o);
        printf("Enter first number: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        printf("Enter second number: ");
        scanf("%d",&y);
        switch(o)
        {
            case '+':
                printf("Sum: %d",x+y);
                break; 
            case '-':
                printf("Subtract: %d",x-y);
                break;
            case '*':
                printf("Multiply: %d",x*y);
                break;
            case '/':
                printf("Division: %d",x/y);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong operator entered.");
        }
        printf("\nEnter y or Y to continue: ");
        scanf(" %c",&r);
    } while((r=='y')||(r=='Y'));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the line (or something similar):

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

After you enter the second number, `'\n'`, the newline character, is left in `stdin` and is being placed in `r`.

You can prove this by adding the following lines after the `while` loop:

```
if(r == '\n')
    printf("\nnewline\n");
```

> Enter operator: '+' or '-' or '*' or '/'
>   *
>   Enter first number: 5
>   Enter second number: 6
>   Multiply: 30
>   Enter y or Y to continue:
>   newline